# input element generates x and y coordinates of mouse click

Tags: html, css, image, button, transform

I have a need to submit page, and i have chosen to use  element to do so with and image that zooms a bit on hover.

Due to the weird nature of the question i found nothing of importance about this subject on google, as i could not formulate it in simple key words.

this is the php.( i know echo html elements is bad practice, but lets focus on problem at hand.)

```
echo '<form method="get">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="v" value="30" />';
echo '<div class="hover01 column">';
echo '<div>';
echo '<figure>';
echo '<input type="image" name="submit" src="http://[img host]/image.jpg" border="0" alt="Submit"/>';
echo '</figure>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</form>';
```

Now when i click on the image i pass in the GET value as it should , but it also passes the x,y location where the click occurred on the image like this

&submit.x=24&submit.y=34

how do i remove the extra two values so that  the URL looks nice and tidy like this

```
http://localhost/vlp/?v=5
```

instead of this

```
http://localhost/vlp/?v=5&submit.x=24&submit.y=34
```

If i change the `<input>` element to `<img>` element then there are no extra GET values, but i need to submit and reload the page with new values and have the image that zooms on hover.

Can this be done without Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just use `<button>` instead to fix the extra GET values in URL